# Problems importing table data from MySQL to Hadoop HDFS on Ubuntu Server via Sqoop

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, hadoop, sqoop

I am testing importing data from MySQL to Hadoop running in pseudo-distributed mode under Ubuntu Server. It looks like the jobs are being submitted nicely, but at some point execution crashes and strangely the underlying user is logged out. After this, pretty much a full restart is required, in addition to some cleaning up in HDFS. What I end up seeing in the namenode and datanode logs look like:

```
2016-10-05 12:10:33,688 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-10-05 12:10:33,681 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

I am using the following versions:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Hadoop 2.7.3
- Sqoop 1.4.6 (sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha)
- MySQL Server 5.7.15
- MySQL Connector/J 5.1.39

The configurations under Hadoop are mostly defaults, for example I haven't yet tuned any memory, disk or CPU related parameters.

Running the same exact scenario on **Ubuntu Server 14.04** works fine.

**Update**

Hadoop configurations below.

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property> 
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>    
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**hadoop-env.sh**

Only thing changed is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Comment: Are your sure the user quota on 16.04 are the same as ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd Both are same - no quotas, or other limits. Also checked total disk space, and it doesn't look to be a problem.

Comment: Same java version ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd Yes, both have version "1.7.0_80". I fire up the environments using the same Ansible scripts.